# How to check Room database integrity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following simple database:

`NameList.kt`

```
@Entity(tableName = "name_list")
data class NameList(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long = 0L,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        var name: String = "")
```

`NameListDao.kt`

```
@Dao
interface NameListDao{    
    @Insert
    fun insert(nameList: NameList)

    @Update
    fun update(nameList: NameList)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM name_list ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<NameList>>
}
```

`NameListRepository.kt`

```
class NameListRepository(private val nameListDao: NameListDao){
    val allNames: LiveData<List<NameList>> = nameListDao.getAll()
}
```

Now, when I change the table in `NameList.kt` by adding/removing a column such as

```
@Entity(tableName = "name_list")
data class NameList(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long = 0L,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
        var firstName: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
        var lastName: String = "")
```

without deleting/changing the database on the phone, the app crashes with the following error message when the database is accessed:

```
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:154)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:142)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:409)
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:324)
E AndroidRuntime:   at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
```

I know this is due to the table being changed (when I delete the database manually and create a new one with the new entity the error is gone).

How can I check the integrity of the database/table (i.e. if they NameList database matches with the one being acessed) before accessing it? 
Does Room provide a particular method, which I missed, for this purpose?

Edit: I think I now got what the version error was about. 
But still, is it possible to check the integrity such that in case of mismatch of old and new database, I can do different things like deleting the old database or having two different databases, etc.?

Comment: Did you read the full exception `Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.` and did you read any documentation about Room? It's quite easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Database version every time you made some changes in the structure. As error said

> You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

Room takes care of you to prevent crashes in runtime.

Comment: By database version, do you mean the version in `@Database(entities = [NameList::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)`? I changed it to `version = 2` and now it works indeed. I didn't get what "version" actually referred to until now. Is it possible to automatically increase the version number such that I do not have to do it manually everytime I change the table?

Comment: @mousou No. You have to do it manually every time when you make any changes in you Database structure.